# How to ensure that command line variables are secure for MathKernel scripts?

Tags: scripting

Suppose I write a Mathematica script, called test.m, like the following:

```
Print["Hello, World!"];
test = ToExpression[$CommandLine[[-1]]];
Print["I'm alive!"];
```

and then I try to call that script from the command line like so:

```
math -script test.m a";Print[LOLOL];Quit[]"
```

I get the following output:

```
"Hello, World!"
LOLOL
```

Naturally, this scares me. I'm hoping to have a way to interpret command line arguments in a secure way. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hard to know what to suggest without some idea of what the arguments are and how they will be used. One way to prevent them evaluating is to use e.g. `ToExpression[$CommandLine, InputForm, HoldComplete]`.

Comment: Let's say that these arguments are positive integers only.

Comment: In that case, you could use `Cases[ToExpression[$CommandLine, InputForm, HoldComplete], HoldComplete[i_Integer] :> i]` to safely retrieve a list of only the integers passed on the command line. Or even `Flatten@StringCases[$CommandLine, i : (DigitCharacter ..) :> ToExpression[i]]`. I'm loath to make this an answer though since this would imply that the question is too localized. Perhaps someone else has a more general approach to suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I agree it's not really an answer to the question I posed, but it happens to work just fine for my current project. Thanks again!